# How to know whether a window is minimised or not?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'd like to know which windows are visible on screen. CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo gives me the list of windows, which is great except it also lists minimised windows as well. 
I tried to use kCGWindowIsOnscreen to detect hidden/minimised windows but it always give TRUE for all windows. Is there any way to detect that somehow?

```
- (void) checkWindows {
NSMutableArray *windows = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);

for (NSDictionary *window in windows) {
    NSString *owner = [window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowOwnerName" ];
    NSString *name = [window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowName" ];
    CFBooleanRef visibleBR = (CFBooleanRef)[window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowIsOnscreen"];
    bool visible = CFBooleanGetValue(visibleBR);

    NSLog(@"%@,%@,Visible:%@",owner,name,visible?@"YES":@"NO");

}
```

}

UPDATE: very strange, it's only Microsoft word. In fact it doesn't have to be hidden, Word creates a full screen window which is not visible but listed among the visible windows.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the dictionaries to check for keys which have a characteristic value for minimized windows? (Honestly, I would have thought that `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly` would exclude minimized windows.)  Also, your `__bridge` cast is a leak.  You're not handing ownership to ARC and you're presumably also not `CFRelease`-ing it.  I recommend using `CFBridgingRelease()` for clarity. It satisfies the need for some sort of `CF*Release*` to balance a `CF*Create*` call while doing the right thing for ARC.

Comment: The alternative to `CFBridgingRelease` would be to change `__bridge`, which tells the compiler “permit this cast with no memory-management action”, to `__bridge_transfer`, which tells it “permit this cast and transfer the object to ARC's management”. `CFBridgingRelease` does the same thing, just with your code using function syntax instead of cast syntax.

Comment: Can't you use the window method    isMiniaturized ?     bool isMiniaturized = [window isMiniaturized];

Comment: @Ken & Peter thanks for pointing out the memory management issues. I didn't think about that. jim these are all visible windows so other app's NSWindow objects cannot be accessed and manipulated. I close this question because the issue was caused by MS Word.

Comment: @JimMerkel: That only works for one's own windows that are represented by NSWindow instances. There's no NSWindow object to send such a message to for a window in another application.

Comment: @PeterHosey: Ok thanks. I should have noticed that as the Op was talking about Microsoft word.

Comment: @JimMerkel: The other application isn't important; it isn't possible to get NSWindow objects for windows of *any* other application.

Comment: @PeterHosey: Understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by MS Word. 
It creates a full screen window which is not visible but listed among the visible windows. CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo lists visible/minimised windows correctly.